# Proposal for the content and the title

Tags: discussion

As TV is a general term and encompasses anything wouldn't be better for this Q&A site to be about Movies and Series with a more specific title? It is my personal opinion that the quality of the questions will be higher that way. Also the content will be more specific hence better questions to answers ratio and answers of better quality.

To be more specific it is my belief that sports and reality shows should be off-topic along with talk shows and other similar shows.

A Q&A site has meaning if there are going to be people in 5 years trying to find answers in it. It is highly unlikely to be someone even in six months trying to find something in here about a football match or a talk show episode. But If the content of this site is focused in Movies and TV Series it is going to be useful. There are countless people asking about a movie from the 80's or 90's something that won't happen for a reality show.

So it is my belief that there is no reason to create a library of answered questions about something that won't have meaning anymore. Sports, talk shows, etc. are programs that are relevant only for a short period of time.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Good suggestion, but while Movies & TV is not ideal, I think it is better than Movies & Series.  Reality TV is on topic here - and a question about a talk show in general - e.g. the hosts style of questioning or something like that would also be perfectly on topic.

Comment: @iandotkelly Yes I know that these are on topic now. The proposal is for them not to be.

Answer (score 6):

**No: Movies & TV is better than Movies & Series** - for the simple reason that we *do deal in TV*.

We don't limit ourselves to *just* films and popular television series, but also tackle anything from soap operas to other general television pieces. I'd be worried about having an unclear title which suggested some things were off-topic when they were perfectly allowable.

As to your point about better content, I'm not sure where you're getting that from. Most of the poor questions we have now revolve around either a lack of details for *identify-this* questions, duplicates or plot explanation requests that are lacking in detail - none of this would be resolved by a change in the Beta title. I don't see how/why this would make a difference.

So in summary - I would vote to stay as we are.

**Edit:**

Just for the record, I created a query on the Stack Exchange to show [our questions per tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/251071/how-many-questions-per-tag), which is what I'm basing my belief about a rename not making a difference on.

Comment: I think that there would be better content with my approach excluding football matches in TV or reality shows but it is just an opinion. I respect yours and also that you placed a comment when downvoting.

Comment: @Adam: We don't get many questions on them, but reality shows are on topic. Same as things like WWE (for now at least!). In other words, we could reduce them, but: a) we don't *want* to. Especially at this stage, the more questions the better, and: b) we have so few right now that I don't see it making a difference to site quality.

Comment: Yes at this point you maybe right.

Comment: I comment about your edit. My proposal stands for the long run not only for the beta stage. I believe that the site must be prepared in case it floods by low quality posts (meaning sport matches or reality shows).

Comment: @Adam: For a start, *reality shows are on topic*. If a *bad question* comes in, that's another thing - but the shows themselves are welcome here, ultimately. As for sport matches... whilst I don't want WWE that much, it's not the end of the world. Other sporting events though are already off topic as defined by our Help Center.

Comment: This is maybe just my personal belief as I find reality shows low quality questions and sports off-topic to a Q&A site like this. That is why I thought to propose so maybe they shouldn't be on topic.

Comment: @Adam: To be honest, that's a different question. As it stands, your question is about changing the site's name and vaguely discusses the content. If *that* was  your proposal, I'd ask it in a separate question (or heavily edit this one to make it clearer)

Comment: I see what you mean. I will edit my post thank you.